# Wordpress - how to access uploads that aren't in the media library?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using Ninja Forms WP Plugin which allows files to be attached to forms and uploaded. It stores them in the wp-content/uploads directory on the server but not in the media library.

I'm trying to programmatically (from a remote server) fetch them from there and then delete them.

I can see there are endpoints in the REST API to access the media library, but I can't see anything about accessing uploaded files that aren't in the media library. Is there any way of doing this?

If not, what would be the best way to access these files? I guess I can fetch them with a standard HTTP request but how could I delete them?

Answer (score 1):

You could register a custom WP API endpoint like `/wp-json/custom-delete-file` (see https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) that does the actual work of deleting the files on the servers file system. For authentication the easiest way would probably be to create a dedicated WP User (e.g. APIUser) whoms credentials (username and password) are then send upon each request to your endpoint, utilizing basic authentication (of course via SSL).

Comment: Thanks - the only thing I'd come up with was to connect by SFTP but this seems a bit of a nicer solution